# How to Control Firefox Centrally under Windows?

Tags: firefox, group-policy, windows-domain

I wonder whether Firefox can be controlled centrally within a Windows domain without using third party software such as PolicyPak.

In particular I want to configure firefox centrally through a group policy such that users cannot change certain settings. The Firefox add-on *GPO support for Firefox and Thunderbird* works fine and would be perfect if users could not deactivate it.

How can I prevent users from deactivating add-ons that are installed globally? Moreover, is there a way to inhibit the installation of add-ons? Generally, is there a water-proof way to control Firefox preferences centrally at all?

I spent some time for research on this but nothing that I found so far was satisfying.

Comment: Firefox can download enforced settings (the ones visible via about:config) from a central server – see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment and http://web.mit.edu/~firefox/www/maintainers/autoconfig.html

Comment: Thanks. I saw the first URL, but I still don't see how to enforce certain add-ons while disabling all other add-ons.

Comment: Since Firefox is open-source, people could just bring in versions that don't obey the Group Policy.